# Where do I get "Find Methods" for Loqate's Address Verification?

Tags: verification, street-address

I'm testing our Loqate's Adress Verification

https://www.loqate.com/resources/support/apis/Capture/Interactive/Retrieve/1/

The API is asking for a Key and Id as part of the required parameters, I have the Key, but for the Id it says in the description that it's a "Find Method" but I don't know where or which they are.

What are valid Id's I can put in there?

Anyone here have any experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function, you mentioned, needs another function to unfold their whole functionality.

First of all you need to get some suggestion made by a search of a user e.g.
https://www.loqate.com/resources/support/apis/Capture/Interactive/Find/1.1/

This function will give you back suggestions. If the type is "address" you can use the given id of the respond to get the whole data of an address you found.

Hope this helps!